# Why is $\sum_{i=1}^N Z_i \leq \frac{1}{Np}$ when $Z_i$ are pairwise independent indicator variables?

Tags: probability

Let $(Z_1,\dots, Z_N)$ be an array of pairwise independent indicator variables with $\Pr(Z_i = 1) = p$ and let $W = \sum_{i=1}^N Z_i$, then $\Pr(W = 0) \leq \frac{1}{Np}$.

I feel there might be a very simple proof but why is this true?

Comment: What is $N_p$ here?

Comment: @Sudix It is $N$ multiplied by $p$.  It is clearer if you look at the source where you see \frac{1}{Np}.

Comment: @donald  Did you mean to just assume pairwise dependence?  My answer posted bleow assumes full independence which is considerably stronger.  What did you intend?

Comment: Yes just pairwise independence

Comment: @donald  Ok, then I will delete my answer (which only address full independence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chebyshev's inequality we have:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-\mathbb{E}\left(W\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{V}\left(W\right)}{\epsilon^2}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad  \mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-Np\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\le\frac{N(p-p^2)}{\epsilon^2}$$

By setting $ϵ:=Np$ we obtain

$$
\mathbb P(W=0)\le \mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-Np\right|\geq Np\right)
\le \frac{N(p-p^2)}{(Np)^2}
= \frac{1-p}{Np}\le \frac{1}{Np}
$$

Which was to show

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Define $n:=N$ and $v≔\sup_{i\in \mathbb N}V(X_i)$.  Then, using the weak law of large numbers we have:

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}$

$$
\frac{v}{n\epsilon^2}\ge
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Z_i-\mathbb{E}\left(Z_i\right)\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\right)
=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(Z_i-p\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\right)
=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\frac{W}{n}-p\right|\geq\epsilon\right)
\\=
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-np\right|\geq n\epsilon\right)
$$

By setting $\epsilon := p$ the above contains the case $\P(W=0)$, so we have

$$
\frac{v}{np^2}\ge
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-np\right|\geq np\right)
\ge \P(W=0)
$$

Now $v= V(X_1)= p-p^2$, and therefore:
$$
\frac{1}{np}\ge\frac{1-p}{np}\ge
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-np\right|\geq np\right)
\ge \P(W=0)
$$

Comment: Can this be proved directly using Chebyshev’s inequality without mentioning the weak law? It might be slightly simpler that way.

Comment: @Anush That's true, Chebyshev makes this proof way shorter: $$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-\mathbb{E}\left(W\right)\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\le\frac{\mathbb{V}\left(W\right)}{\epsilon^2}\qquad\Leftrightarrow\qquad 
\mathbb{P}\left(\left|W-np\right|\geq\epsilon\right)\le\frac{n(p-p^2)}{\epsilon^2}$$ and setting $\epsilon:=np$ brings us directly to the last line

Comment: Could you edit the answer you have given?

Comment: @Anush I've added the answer as community wiki. I'd prefer to keep this answer the way it is, as I'd say this is the canonical way to find the proof. We have pairwise independence, know the expectancy and variance, and want to find an (upper) estimate of a probability of a sum of variables. So we pick the strongest tool we have that fits the bill, which is the weak law of large numbers.

Comment: Surely the weakest tool, that is the most elementary solution, is best?

Comment: @Anush The way I'd try proof a statement is by trying out the tools that seem as if they might work in decreasing order generality. It's the only way I can ever hope to cope with the infinitely many statements that math has to offer, as it limits the amount of them I have to keep in my mind. Yes, using weaker machinery means more elegant and simpler solutions, but those are, I'd say, text book proofs - they only serve as proof, and give no intuition on how to solve the problem.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to teach it to a student and don't want to make claims you can't show a proof for, elementary is certainly better.